# Curiouser and Curiouser on the New Profile Page Bounty Tab

Tags: support, bug, profile-page

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Bounty tab in profile has oddly-behaving sort/filter options](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118596/bounty-tab-in-profile-has-oddly-behaving-sort-filter-options)

I **KNOW** I have **one** active bounty (let us just start off with that).

When I 1st go to my profile page and click on `bounties` it looks like this, showing all the bounties I have ever offered:

[image: ok step one]

Ok that is fine.

Now onto clicking on active bounties:
[image: ok step two of our plan to take over the universe]

**FINE**

But now when I reload the profile page and click on `bounties` It ends up automatically showing the view as if I had clicked on `active`.

Is there a way to get back to that original view?  or is this [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)?

---

Adding the [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) tag as per [Michael Mrozek](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/114363/155556)'s answer

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you want to see all bounties you've offered, switch to the "offered" filter; it's by design that profile pages remember the filter you've selected. However, it looks like a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) that by default it highlights "active" but shows inactive bounties