# Bounty tab in profile has oddly-behaving sort/filter options

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounties, profile-page

If you're viewing an unfiltered bounty listing in someone's profile<sup>[[jeff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood?tab=bounties)]</sup> the header **N bounties** isn't capitalized, though every other profile section header is.

[image: 4 bounties]

I think the actual problem is that the unfiltered bounty listing isn't supposed to be displayed. Once you select a filter (*active*, *offered* or *earned*) there seems to be no way to clear it and return to the unfiltered listing. It also doesn't really make sense to throw offered and earned bounties in together.

---

*edit:* This doesn't use the header in question, but you can get the unsorted bounty list with a variety of other headers by using different `sort` values in the query string:

[image]

- [`&sort=0` or `&sort=votes` uses **Votes bounties**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood?tab=bounties&sort=0).
- [`&sort=1` or `&sort=activity` uses **Activity bounties**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood?tab=bounties&sort=1).
- [`&sort=2` or `&sort=newest` uses **Newest bounties**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood?tab=bounties&sort=2).
- [`&sort=3` or `&sort=views` uses **Views bounties**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood?tab=bounties&sort=3).
- [`&sort=4` or `&sort=added` uses **Added bounties**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood?tab=bounties&sort=4).
- [`&sort=5` or `&sort=post` uses **Post bounties**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood?tab=bounties&sort=5).
- [`&sort=6` or `&sort=time` uses **Time bounties**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood?tab=bounties&sort=6).
- [`&sort=7` or `&sort=graph` uses **Graph bounties**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood?tab=bounties&sort=7).
- [`&sort=8` or `&sort=suggestions` uses **Suggestions bounties**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood?tab=bounties&sort=8).
- [`&sort=9` or `&sort=reviews` uses **Reviews bounties**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood?tab=bounties&sort=9).
- [`&sort=10` or `&sort=revisions` uses **Revisions bounties**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood?tab=bounties&sort=10).
- [`&sort=11` or `&sort=comments` uses **Comments bounties**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood?tab=bounties&sort=11).
- [`&sort=12` or `&sort=badges` uses **Badges bounties**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood?tab=bounties&sort=12).
- [`&sort=13` or `&sort=posts` uses **Posts bounties**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood?tab=bounties&sort=13).
- [`&sort=14` or `&sort=accepts` uses **Accepts bounties**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood?tab=bounties&sort=14).
- [`&sort=15` or `&sort=answers` uses **Answers bounties**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood?tab=bounties&sort=15).
- [`&sort=19` or `&sort=name` uses **Name bounties**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood?tab=bounties&sort=19).
- [`&sort=20` or `&sort=recent` uses **Recent bounties**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood?tab=bounties&sort=10).
- [`&sort=21` or `&sort=class` uses **Class bounties**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood?tab=bounties&sort=21).
- [`&sort=22` or `&sort=all` uses **All bounties**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood?tab=bounties&sort=22).
- [`&sort=N`, where `N` is any other integer, gives you **N bounties**.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood?tab=bounties&sort=-123456789)

Also,

- [`sort=16` is the same as `sort=active`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood?tab=bounties&sort=16)
- [`sort=17` is the same as `sort=offered`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood?tab=bounties&sort=17)
- [`sort=18` is the same as `sort=earned`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood?tab=bounties&sort=18)

I guess the tabs share the same sort options, internally, but bounties are the only tab that also uses it for filtering and modifying the title and so is alone in having this bug.

Comment: *the header N bounties isn't capitalized* Watch out or Jeff may come to your house and bludgeon you with a giant capital "B"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Curiouser and Curiouser on the New Profile Page Bounty Tab](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114360/curiouser-and-curiouser-on-the-new-profile-page-bounty-tab)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "If you're viewing an unfiltered bounty listing in someone's profile"

That shouldn't happen in the first place, it will default to "active" bounties...so the capitalization is correct, it should never appear by itself was the bug.

Handling of wacky sort cases passed in will be addressed in the next build, if you pass in crap that doesn't make sense, you'll get the default.  Thanks for causing spam in the error log, jerk! :)

Comment: I wasn't doing anything wacky in the first place, I only started playing with these options trying to recreate the bug I saw (and never found query values that produce that header). I just noticed it while viewing someone's profile.

Comment: @Jeremy - You had a bad sort that stickied from a previous attempt...there's no way to get to that a bad sort via the UI unless I've missed something major

Comment: Reproduced: I logged into a different account in a new private browsing session and went to a bounty tab. ["active" was shown as selected but the header said "1 bounty" and the listed bounty wasn't active](http://i.stack.imgur.com/y3ZRV.png). When I clicked on "active" it changed to "0 active bounties". From here, I don't know any sort values to restore the exact heading of "1 bounty".

Comment: Actually, no need to log in to another account. Just viewing a profile anonymously in a private browsing session produces the incorrect header and filter.

Comment: @Jeremy - ah found your entry point...already fixed in the next build

Comment: Same question as mine: http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/816994#816994 http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114360/155556

Comment: Will invalid values also be ignored for the other tabs? The activity tab will save an invalid value, but give you an error page for it. The result is that by linking you to `/users/1114/jeremy-banks?tab=activity&sort=0` I can prevent you from being able to see anybody's activity tabs (until you manually correct the sort value).

Comment: @Jeremy - yup, they're fixed as well.